# Overriding Product view page in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, products

I am overriding product page for customization, but my template is not setting.

**[Namespace]/[Modulename]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]_[Modulename]::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**[Namespace]/[Modulename]/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
<h1>Product view Page</h1>

...
//core module code
...
```

and I run the `flush, clean` command also.

Any help?

Comment: Add block instead of arguments

Comment: @RonakChauhan, I want to add just one line of code, remaining code will sampe.

Comment: @ Manoj Kumar Do you  want to add extra info or change existing elements.

Comment: @RonakChauhan,  I can add extra info successfully in the page last, but I want ot add extra info beside the `SKU`.

Comment: You can override the phtml file not a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add extra information beside SKU, overriding (`setTemplate`) entire template may not be a good idea, you can add something like as i added some example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Solwin Infotech
 * Solwin Product Print Page
 * 
 * @category   Solwin
 * @package    Solwin_Printpage
 * @copyright  Copyright © 2006-2016 Solwin (https://www.solwininfotech.com)
 * @license    https://www.solwininfotech.com/magento-extension-license/
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="[Namespace]\[Modulename]\Block\Product\Extrainfo" name="custom.extrainfo"  after="product.info.sku"  template="[Namespace]_[Modulename]::test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```